# There is too much padding in the "blog" sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The title pretty much explains it, but the padding of the "blog" sidebar is incorrect:

> [image: Screenshot]

There is too much space on the left of the text. Can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the offending styles (not sure when/why they were added, but should have been removed when it was redesigned).

With you in the next build.

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect now !

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed on Chrome with Windows 7 Professional x64.
Seems to be related to the `div.bulleten-item-type` CSS rule:

[image]

Indeed, editing the `width` from `25px` to `15px` (shaving off 10px), fixes it:

```
bulletin-item-type {
  width: 15%;
}
```

as per se:

[image]

This seems to be a partial fix, however, since Chrome ignores `width` on the `content`:

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer btw !